# how to find gpa in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm tired to using codeigniter sql query but not working, see active records and searching many question in stackoverflow and many other's find some solution but still not working. Here in my sql code:

```
$grate_point=$this->db->get_where('grade',array('class_id'=>$class_id,'subject_id'=>$row2['subject_id'],'mark_from <='=>$obtained_marks,'mark_upto >='=>$obtained_mark_query))->row();
```

I have some marks like 75, when I check maximum and minimum value where A+=(mark_from=80-mark_upto=100),A= (mark_from=70-mark_upto=79) and many others... I need find to Gpa like A+,A,A-,B.....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to GPA since we don't use it in my country...
But I think you may need all marks to get the GPA. Don't use row() method but result_array() and then read your array with foreach(... as row).
If you explain me the GPA concept I may be more precise with my answer. But try changing row() first.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But it have many value like A+,A,A-,B,C,D